# Model POCO, Rest API and contract

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, model

I have generally a simple situation but I wonder how to resolve it in a simple and clear way.
So...
I have a model of something - for example model of user where there are a lot of fields among others there is an Email field.

```
public class UserEntity : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SecretSomething { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

When I want to hide something on frontend then I can use JsonIgnore. Then - for example - the secret field will be hidden and never shown on frontend.

I would like to do something similar with the Email field - I need this field FROM frontend but I don't want to pass this field TO frontend from backend.

Can I do it?
Of course, I could create a "contract" model where the Email field would not exist but maybe there is another smart way?

Best Regards,
Krzysztof.

Comment: Have different models for the API and Backend, search for some more info about DTO (Data Transfer Object), when using DTO we have one for each layer of the code

Comment: No. This idea is not good because of security. In the network, you could see other data even if you will use other models in frontend.

Comment: Well there is nothing 100% safe, if you need the field from the front end, you need the email when creating? and you don't want to give the email when is to read? If yes, create one model to create and another to read

Comment: Exactly like you said. I need the Email field when the user is created but I don't need it and I don't want it when the user is loaded somewhere.
Of course, I know that a new model would resolve that problem - for example, I could create the method "ToSafeObject" in my current model and it would create a new model with important fields, but still, maybe there is a better idea. I would prefer not to create a similar class. Maybe a better idea would be to create my own JsonIgnore but I'm not sure that I could recognize the context.